# ¿Como creo una llave foránea en MySQL usando Navicat?

Tags: mysql

Cuando sigo el procedimiento estandar guarda la llave foranea como un index en vez de una foreign key. Soy nuevo en bases de datos.

Comment: Hola bienvenido Hugo. Te recomiendo hacer el [Tour](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para tener una mejor respuesta y la pregunta se entienda. Con respeto a tu tema... yo al principio empeze usando navicat pero  a la larga me di cuenta que es mas facil codearla que usando un soft.

Comment: me sucede lo mismo, ¿has encontrado la solución?

Answer (score 1):

Muy fácil.

Estoy usando sqlite de ejemplo, pero funciona igual para mysql (y creo para los otros gestores soportados del mismo modo).

Suponiendo que tenemos dos tablas con las siguientes columnas:

- *La tabla user:*

[image: tabla user]

- *Y la tabla message:*

[image: tabla messages]

Verificamos que "user_id" (que se va convertir en clave foránea) de la tabla "messages" tenga los mismos atributos que "user_id" de la tabla "user" como en las imágenes de arriba (campos marcados en rojo), de lo contrario va tirar error y va hacer solo los indexes.

Luego en la tabla "message" vamos a la pesaña foreign keys:

[image: foreign keys1]

Seleccionamos "user_id" como clave foránea:

[image: foreign keys2]

Elegimos la tabla donde vamos enlazar la clave foránea (en este caso "user"):

[image: foreign keys3]

Buscamos el campo que será nuestra clave foránea:

[image: foreign keys4]

*No tan necesario => Escribimos un nombre para nuestra clave foránea:*

[image: foreign keys5]

Y punchamos guardar:

[image: foreign keys6]

Y si todo salió bien obviamente no va mostrar error y se va guardar nuestra foreign key.

[image: foreign keys7]

Y ya.